# Accessing flag in react native router flux scene

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, react-native-router-flux

I have a scene called places.js and in that I have passed props for a flag I set up. With two scenes cities.js and countries.js, I have  no problem passing the props to them individually. However, I have setup these two scenes to be in tabs using react-native-router-flux-tabs. The problem is here, when I navigate to the tabbed scene, the props for flag appear to be saved and rendered only once. I am confused as to why this is happening when passing props to those scenes without including them in a tabbed scene works. My code is below. Any help is appreciated.I know the props pass through at least once because I logged it but why they aren't stored is my question.
[this is the setup for the tabbed scene in router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M67Vg.png)
[This is how I am navigating to the tabbed scene while passing props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUoG9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance issues, the Tabs just render once. If you are using RNRFv4 you should use the onEnter and onExit props of your scenes where your navigator is defined.

```
<Scene key="welcome" tabs swipeEnabled={true} hideNavBar >
        <Scene
          key="nav"
          component={NavContainer}
          onEnter={onNavigate}
          initial />

        <Scene
            key="scanner"
            component={Scan}
            onEnter={onThis}
            onExit={onThis}
        />

        <Scene key="search" component={Search} />
</Scene>


const onNavigate = () => {
  // some logic
  return true;
};

const onThis = () => {
  // some logic
  return true;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Upgrading to v4 fixed my problem.

Comment: Remember that if you are using redux and you want to dispatch some actions from there you can import your store and use store.dispatch() to dispatch actions! Glad I could help! ;)